# Twitter-Bootstrap - how to create this layout with column spanning two rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create a layout as shown in the diagrams. There are two challenges that I don't know how to solve about this layout:

- in `col-md`, A and D are to take up any available vertical space on the page, while B and C are arranged vertically one after the other taking as much space as required.
- in `col-sm`, D and A are not to be vertically aligned with B and C, but rather taking as much space as needed.

**col-lg**

[image: col-lg]

**col-md**

[image: col-md]

**col-sm**

[image: col-sm]